# Help looping through table rows and saving selected to an object in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, list, checkbox

I am trying to figure out what the best way to save values to my database based on whether or not a row's checkbox in a table is checked or not.

In my ASP.NET MVC application that I am trying to save a selected row (a location) to a "locationtemplate" object.

What I want to be able to do is for each selected row (a location) in the table on my view, save it to the locationtemplate object. I am not sure where I should perform the check on whether the row is selected or not.

View Code (so far):

```
foreach(var locationTemplateLocationRow in Model.LocationTemplateLocationRows)
{
 <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="LocationToAdd"/></td>
  <td><%= locationTemplateLocationRow.Name%></td>
  <td><%= locationTemplateLocationRow.LastDateSent%></td>
 </tr>
}
```

Based on what is selected I would like to send my list of checked locations to my save action on my controller and go from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand is that you want to bind to a list object (locationTemplate) where each object will contain a boolean property to hold value of checkbox. For this purpose plz go through this [tutorial](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)